# Adjust 3D-plot (with pgf TikZ) to textwidth or linewidth. Make 3D plot bigger

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

I want to plot a **3D-plot** with **pgf TikZ** importing csv data. Everything works fine.

[image]

However, I want to make the whole graphic bigger, that it fits to the textwitdh and is better adjusted in the document flow.
Anybody knows how that works? I thought something like:

```
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{...}
```

but I wasn't able to find something like this. I would be SO happy for any kind of help! Cheers! :)

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,]{geometry} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering      
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                view = {50}{45},
                ymin=0.0068,
                ymax=0.01,
                zmin=15,
                zmax=22,
                ytick={0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01},
                ztick={15, 18.5, 22},
                grid,
                grid style={semithick, densely dotted},
                xlabel={$f_0$ in GHz},
                ylabel={$k$},
                zlabel={$BP_1$ in mm},
                ]
            \addplot3[color = teal, only marks, ultra thick] table[x=f0, y=k, z=para1, col sep=semicolon, /pgf/number format/read comma as period] {3D_k12.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{\label{fig:3D} sample caption}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest, you set the width (and maybe also height) option of the `axis` environment to something like `width=0.9\textwidth` as below.

This won't set the width of the graphic exactly to `\textwidth`, but you can change the appearance both horizontally and vertically to whatever you like, separately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,]{geometry} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering      
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                view = {50}{45},
                width=0.9\textwidth,
                height=0.5\textwidth,
                ymin=0.0068,
                ymax=0.01,
                zmin=15,
                zmax=22,
                ytick={0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01},
                ztick={15, 18.5, 22},
                grid,
                grid style={semithick, densely dotted},
                xlabel={$f_0$ in GHz},
                ylabel={$k$},
                zlabel={$BP_1$ in mm},
                ]
            \addplot3[color = teal, only marks, ultra thick] table[x=f0, y=k, z=para1, col sep=semicolon, /pgf/number format/read comma as period] {3D_k12.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{\label{fig:3D} sample caption}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The result (with arbitrary data in the csv file):
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That's actually pretty simple, now I'm feeling a bit dump :D But really, thanks a lot!